# What number of probes are needed to avoid collision in hashing?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I have placed even values (i.e., 0, 2, 4, 6, .., 19996, 19998) in my hash table such that:
Value 0 is stored at home address 0, value 2 is stored at home address 2. Similarly, value 16,382 is stored at home address 16,382, but values 16,384 to 19,998 will have collisions.

Now to avoid collisions what number of probes needed to search for the target values from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, till 19999 ?

Comment: What programming language do you use? What data structure do you use?

Comment: @Alex Python and openAddressHashing Dictionary.